# Is this a valid Sinatra route handler?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Is this a valid route handler?

```
post '/lists/:id/delete' do
   #delete list
   ...
end
```

I can't get it to fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. But it will only fire when you do a HTTP POST request, e.g. submit a form using the `post` method:

```
<form action="/lists/17/delete" method="post">
  ...
</form>
```

If you enter the same URL in you browser, however, a HTTP GET request will be fired. If this is what you want, you should replace `post` with `get` in your route.

A great place to start: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.

Comment: I don't think the other routes should be in conflict in any way.

Comment: Here is the erb template fragment:

<td>
              <form action="<%= "/list/#{list.id}/delete" %>" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete">
              </form>